# Add Environment variables in a docker container, even if they are not declared in the Docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im passing a new enviroment variable when i run a docker image with

```
docker run myapp -p 8081:80  --env NEW_VIROMENT_VARIABLE=VALUE
```

`NEW_VIROMENT_VARIABLE` is not in the Dockerfile like `ENV NEW_VIROMENT_VARIABLE`
Im trying to create new variables even if are not declarated within the Dockerfile, is this possible?

Comment: Options like `-p` and `-e` need to be _before_ the image name `myapp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its stated in the docker docs, it should be done like this:

```
$ docker run --env VAR1=value1 --env VAR2=value2 ubuntu env
```

Comment: Thanks @Vahid I thought the order didn't matter

Comment: @svladimirrc no worries, can you mark it as the correct answer please, thanks